# Can 借家 and 家賃 be used interchangeably

Tags: words

I just come across these two words used to describe "home rental". However, I want to know the difference between these two words and whether they can be used interchangeably.

My understanding is that

- 家賃 can be used to refer to:

  1. To let
  2. The rent (money)
- 借家 refers to the house being rented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, No.

Your understanding is correct except that 家賃 does not mean "to let"
(only your #2), thus not interchangeable.

If you are confused, may be this way of thinking helps you a lot.

Chinese origin Kanji, when divided, the former is always (not entirely) adjective or verb. (This becomes sometimes different for JAPANESE KANJI because JAPANESE KANJI is not actually, KANJI.)

家賃　⇒　家(house's) / 賃 (money/rent)　⇒　the house rent.

借家　⇒　借(rent (v. tr.)) / 家 (house)　⇒　a house rented.

Have a good night.